# How to Select Custom line AJAX in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

My problem is that when I delete a line we can only do I delete a row and jQuery practice for other lines will not be executed.

```
<script>
    $('#destroy').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var token = $('input[name="_token"]').attr('value');
        var id = $('#destroy').data("id");

        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "{{ url('/category') }}" + '/' + id + '/delete',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {"id": id, '_token': token},
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.msg)
            }
        });

        console.log("It failed");
    });
</script>
```

line:

```
<tr id="destroy_">
    <td>
        <a id="destroy" data-id="{{$cat->id}}" href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="{{action('categoryController@update',[$cat->id])}}">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="{{action('categoryController@show', [$cat->id])}}">
            {{$cat->category}}
        </a>
    </td>
    <th class="text-right">{{$cat->id}}</th>
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Do all rows have `id="destroy"`? Ids are unique so you can't have more than one element with the ID `destroy`.

Comment: i changed example: `destroy-845` but not run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ID's for actions that are repeated in a table is a bad idea if you don't name them dynamically. Either way I suggest using anything other than an ID, for example a custom data attribute. So use this for your delete links:

```
<a data-delete data-id="{{$cat->id}}" href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

And in your JS code instead of `#destroy` you can now use the following selector to match them:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-delete]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var token = $('input[name="_token"]').attr('value');
    var id = $(this).data("id");

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "{{ url('/category') }}" + '/' + id + '/delete',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {"id": id, '_token': token},
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.msg)
        },
        error: function () {
            // Also the failed request should be handled here
            // not below the ajax call because it's asynchronous
            console.log("It failed");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i get this error `Call to a member function delete() on a non-object`

Comment: Please post your backend code, I'm guessing the processing takes place in a Laravel controller action.

Comment: not work i get error from id deleted and `Call to a member function delete() on a non-object` because this is deleted :(

Comment: my controller  `public function destroy($id)
    {
            $category = Category::find($id);
            $category->delete();
            return response()->json(['msg' => 'deleted']);
    }`

Comment: You PHP code looks fine. Did you include all the changes I made to your JavaScript code from my answer? I also replaced this line of code `var id = $('#destroy').data("id");` with this line of code `var id = $(this).data("id");`. If you didn't make that change then it might be the reason for your error because the ID wasn't passed correctly.

Comment: Could not open because it is still the old value and the new value still does not get a practice run just once.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "practice run", please explain.

Comment: When I run operation is performed only once and the second time code will not run

Comment: Are the contents of that table modified dynamically via AJAX at some point?

Comment: Every time I run the code is deleted and the first row id cache and be the first line of code fails

Comment: Then that's probably the issue then. Since the `[data-delete]` elements are being replaced after the initial `click` was bound, the second time there's no event handler anymore since the elements are all new to the DOM. So you need to [delegate the event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) handler to listen through a parent element such as `$(document)`. I've updated my answer with the necessary changes.

Comment: this code `$(this).parent().parent().remove();` remove first line of list no line is selected